# Invalid Http response

Tags: java, inputstream

Tenho o seguinte bloco de código

```
public void read( String url ){
       try{
            urlNormal = new URL("http://"+url+"/sistema.cgi?lermc=0,33");
            URLConnection conn = urlNormal.openConnection();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String s = null;
            Map<String, String> valores = new HashMap<>();
            int i = 0;
            String nova = "";

            List<String> dadosRecuperados = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] dadosSeparados = null;
            if (null != (s = input.readLine())) {
                nova = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                dadosSeparados = nova.split(",");
            }

            for( int j = 0; j< dadosSeparados.length; j++ ){
                System.out.println(dadosSeparados[j]);
            }

               // valores.put( campos[i], s );
            //}
        }
        catch(java.net.MalformedURLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Quando faço a leitura leitura de uma url ele dá a seguinte mensagem:

> Invalid Http response

O dado que é retornado da url é assim:

> `[127.63,28.87,3684.71,2621.41,0.71,0.00,0.00,0.00,2589.45,0.00,127.23,29.70,3779.10,-2439.51,-0.65,0.00,0.00,0.00,2886.24,0.00,126.52,29.33,3711.14,-580.26,-0.16,-1.00,-1.00,-1.00,3665.50,59.58,29.30,38.60]`

Gostaria de saber o que tem de errado

Comment: Seria legal voce explicasse o que o método faz pra pessoa nao ter que ler pra descobrir. Se o problema é no response entao ou talvez está chamando com parametros errados ou é um problema no serviço.

Tente verificar isso

Comment: Creio eu que é o formato

Comment: O que retorna essa url?

Comment: [127.63,28.87,3684.71,2621.41,0.71,0.00,0.00,0.00,2589.45,0.00,127.23,29.70,3779.10,-2439.51,-0.65,0.00,0.00,0.00,2886.24,0.00,126.52,29.33,3711.14,-580.26,-0.16,-1.00,-1.00,-1.00,3665.50,59.58,29.30,38.60]

Comment: Isso é o que ele deveria retornar mesmo e voce está com problema na leitura ou o response está vindo errado?

Comment: Você consegue fazer um teste com qualquer outra URL?

Comment: Sim. Na outra funcionou

Comment: Quem mostra esses dados aí é o arduíno

Comment: Você pode adicionar o StackTrace do erro na sua pergunta?

Comment: Eu tinha antes, mas removi